# Automatic switching of a constant current circuit

Tags: arduino, relay, pwm, power-electronics, constant-current

I'm running 14 ~3W (700mA) LEDs in series on a constant current LED Driver that handles between 36-65V output.  The driver runs the LEDs at 600mA.

The heatsinks I've attached are pretty small, and if I put my fingers on one, it heats up in about 2 minutes or so, and then takes about 20 seconds to get cold again.

I'd like to use an Arduino to turn on and off the circuit, for roughly these periods.

I wrote a basic sketch to handle the Arduino part to keep a relay on for this period...

```
  s_l = millis() % 120000;
  on = (s_l < 100000) ;
  digitalWrite(relayPin, on);
```

I have relay modules, and transistors lying around... but I'm not sure how well they will play with a constant current circuit.  The LEDs don't care if I am PWM'ing, but maybe the driver will get some weird feedback loop if I mess with it?

I'd prefer to use transistors, because the relays clicking will probably drive me crazy - but I will take any solution.  What is my best option?

Just a relay on the AC side?  I'd prefer not to work with AC, as it is a lot more dangerous.

Thanks in advance...

Edit:  picture of constant current LED driver guts:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What LED driver are you using? There may be numerous methods that cold be used, but it will depend on the details of the driver.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a mysterious Chinese driver... bit.ly/1PSbctI ...  I can take a picture of its guts if that will help?

Comment: a picture may be helpful. I would be very wary of interrupting the current path (as Ross suggests) *unless* the thing is known to have open LED sensing (the output voltage can rise to dangerous levels if not).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use an N type mosfet on the low side of your LED string and switch the earth end. Being on the low side will mean that you can drive it on/off directly from an Arduino output.

edit. Yes your diagram is fine, except... be sure to connect the Arduino's ground to the N-Mosfet's S terminal.

edit2. That mosfet's Vgs is a bit high, so you may find the Arduino struggles to turn the mosfet on hard enough to avoid heating. What other n-mosfets do you have?

Comment: Sorry, my electronese is poor.  Do you mean like this?  http://salient.koding.io/LED_MOSFET.png

Comment: Do you think this chip might work?  http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfz24n.pdf